# get value customize of output json_encode() by jQuery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I insert data with `json_encode()` in database, want get just values `name_units` on row `units` in database. how is it?

This is output database in code php(by `json_encode()`):
**my_table=>units=>name_units**

> [{"name":"jack","units":[{"name_units":"salam","price_units":"74,554","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman"]},{"name_units":"mokhles","price_units":"4,851,269","checkbox_units":["mobleman","tv"]},{"name_units":"fadat","price_units":"85,642","checkbox_units":["minibar","mobleman","tv"]}]}]

```
var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'url',
    data: dataObj,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
/////////////////////*HERE/////////////////////
        $.each(data, function(a, b) {
            //alert(b.units[name_units]);
            $('<p id="' + b.units[name_units] + '">' + b.units[name_units] + '</p>').appendTo('.class');
        });
/////////////////////HERE*/////////////////////
    };
})
```

Comment: Given the json ouput, you can access named_units directly in the each loop using `b.name_units`, you don't need `b.units[name_units]`

Comment: my output is tow row, 1.name 2.units. i test `b.name_units` and get alert `undefined`.

Comment: Can you post the JSON that is being returned as is? Am still not clear if my_table is also being returned ot it just starts from units?

Comment: you read following post and my comment, it is clear for you.

Comment: I already posted an answer based the info you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function(a, b) {
    $.each(b.units, function(c, d){
        $('<p id="' + d.name_units  + '">' + d.name_units + '</p>').appendTo('.class');
    });
});
```

Also, its a good idea to use [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) for this scenario

Comment: I tend to use jQuery templates as I don't like using string concatenation specially when I need to use lot of properties from source object to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

units is an array, therefore you need to reference an item in the array or loop through all items in that array. `b.units[0].name_units`

Edit: like i said, you would have to loop through them.

```
$.each(b.units,function(i,unit){
  alert(unit.name_units);
});
```

you could also use a for loop if you would prefer.

Comment: how can get each value(all) `name_units` together(`each` or `foreach`). this your code only get a `name_units`=> **salam**. i want **salam** & **mokhles** & **fadat**